# Verifying the number of times a line crosses other lines

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-desktop, intersection, topology, hydrology

I have a series of lines that represent streams. I have a stream line and two flowpath lines in one feature class and two banklines in another feature class. Total of five lines. I then have a feature class with cross-section lines that intersect these lines. These are all in a personal geodatabase.

[image: See picture below]

I need the cross-sections to intersect each line only once. Because the five lines can be convoluted, sometimes a cross-section will cross one of the five stream lines more than once. Is there a way to identify which cross-section lines cross more then five lines?

It's a big data set so sifting through each cross-section individually is not optimal.

Comment: What it's the difference between stream line and 2 flow path lines? Can you edit your question and upload an image of what you are describing?

Comment: which intersection point do you want to keep when you have multiple intersections for a single line?

Answer (score 5):

If you run an intersection between the 2 different line feature classes, and specify the output type to be Point, then you should be able to do a count of the ids in the point table of the input lines.